# Bitmap to svg path

Tags: javascript, svg, bitmap, pixel, svg-path

I don't know how to make this algorithm in JavaScript/Node.js that converts bitmaps into svg paths pixel by pixel:

[image: input] [image: input]

```
// input
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

// output
<path d="M2 2 h6 v2 h1 v2 h-1 v2 h-6 v-2 h-1 v-2 h1 v-2 M4 4 v2 h2 v-2 z">
```

Does anyone know how the algorithm should work?

Any pseudocode would help.

Tools does the similar approach:

- https://github.com/59naga/pixel-to-svg
- https://github.com/brainshave/sharpvg
- https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/XbxvNj
- http://drububu.com/tutorial/bitmap-to-vector.html

Comment: So Your question is "I'm creating an algorithm. I don't know how to make this algorithm"?

Comment: yes, I will update the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can converts pixels to SVG path string like this.

[image]

Using this algorithm, I made script coverts pixel art to SVG.

http://defghi1977.html.xdomain.jp/tech/img2svg3/dot2svg3.htm

(Sorry this page is written in Japanese.)

Comment: yes thats basically it, but the step from one to two got me into trouble, how did you joined the overlapping vectors in your algoritm?

Comment: For example, if a vector was presented by `x:y:direction` (string), the inverse of `0:0:right` vector is `1:0:left`. So you can push vector to (normal) object as key for searching inverse vector.

Comment: I think that I have it, is your code available on internet? GitHub? By the way I have added more tools that solves the same problem and most of it comes form Japan :) look at the question